# How to check Erlang cookie on RabbitMQ to ensure that it has been changed from the default?

Tags: cookies, rabbitmq, erlang

As a security precaution, I know default cookie values are as dangerous as default credential combinations.
So can anyone help me with how to verify if the Erlang cookie has been changed from default?

As per the document, erlang is stored in the local file.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie

> RabbitMQ nodes and CLI tools (e.g. rabbitmqctl) use a cookie to
>   determine whether they are allowed to communicate with each other. For
>   two nodes to be able to communicate they must have the same shared
>   secret called the Erlang cookie. The cookie is just a string of
>   alphanumeric characters up to 255 characters in size. It is usually
>   stored in a local file. The file must be only accessible to the owner
>   (e.g. have UNIX permissions of 600 or similar). Every cluster node
>   must have the same cookie.
>
> If the file does not exist, Erlang VM will try to create one with a
>   randomly generated value when the RabbitMQ server starts up. Using
>   such generated cookie files are appropriate in development
>   environments only. Since each node will generate its own value
>   independently, this strategy is not really viable in a clustered
>   environment.

How can we check if it is a default value as Erlang VM will try to create one with a randomly generated value when the RabbitMQ server starts up.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie file is not present, the Erlang VM creates one with random content. There is no "default value".

If you would like to use your own randomly-generated cookie value, you can create the cookie file yourself.